# Should I trim the flowers off a new blackcurrant bush?

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning

I bought a starter cutting for a blackcurrant bush - it's doing very well, looking healthy. The problem is that there are also some flowers developing, and a pamphlet that came with the cutting said I should trim any fruit that grows. Should I trim the flowers off so the young bush will put more energy into vegetative growth (nipping the fruit problem "in the bud")?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean a bare root or potted plant? Did you prune it when you planted it? Either way, I would prune each stem back to 4 or 5 buds. Then you can remove any flowers that are left, if there are any. Good luck with it! My black currants are some of my favorite plants in my garden.